# user data is not running at launch aws ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch an ec2 linux instance (linux 2 ami) and while doing that in the user data, I am trying to 
get node js installed, and at the same time install git. 
Then I am trying to get clone my github repo and then start the node js server, all this done in the userdata.

I am trying to check everywhere, in the cloudlog init file to find some error why my user data is not working.

Here are the codes.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash 
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 4.4.5
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install git -y
git clone https://github.com/myname/one_user.git
cd one_user

dnsaddress=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
export dns_name=${dnsaddress}
npm install -y
node server.js
```

The code below is from the cloud init log file.

```
Cloud-init v. 18.2-72.amzn2.0.6 running 'init-local' at Sun, 10 Feb 2019 15:49:35 +0000. Up 4.93 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 18.2-72.amzn2.0.6 running 'init' at Sun, 10 Feb 2019 15:49:38 +0000. Up 7.42 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |          10.0.1.72          | 255.255.255.0 | global | 0e:1f:76:6a:3c:6c |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::c1f:76ff:fe6a:3c6c/64 |       .       |  link  | 0e:1f:76:6a:3c:6c |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route |   Destination   | Gateway  |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |     0.0.0.0     | 10.0.1.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: |   1   |     10.0.1.0    | 0.0.0.0  |  255.255.255.0  |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   2   | 169.254.169.254 | 0.0.0.0  | 255.255.255.255 |    eth0   |   UH  |
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   9   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   11  |    local    |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   12  |   ff00::/8  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
Cloud-init v. 18.2-72.amzn2.0.6 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 10 Feb 2019 15:49:39 +0000. Up 8.99 seconds.
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 3265.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  31 M RSS (321 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sun Feb 10 15:49:38 2019 - 00:02 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3265
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  70 M RSS (361 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sun Feb 10 15:49:38 2019 - 00:04 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3265
 --> 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 from amzn2-core removed (updateinfo)
 --> 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 from amzn2-core removed (updateinfo)
1 package(s) needed (+0 related) for security, out of 3 available
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.14.88-88.76.amzn2 will be updated
---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.14.94-89.73.amzn2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package           Arch        Version                    Repository       Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 kernel-tools      x86_64      4.14.94-89.73.amzn2        amzn2-core      111 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 111 k
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : kernel-tools-4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64                      1/2 
  Cleanup    : kernel-tools-4.14.88-88.76.amzn2.x86_64                      2/2 
  Verifying  : kernel-tools-4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64                      1/2 
  Verifying  : kernel-tools-4.14.88-88.76.amzn2.x86_64                      2/2 

Updated:
  kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.14.94-89.73.amzn2                                     

Complete!
Cloud-init v. 18.2-72.amzn2.0.6 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 10 Feb 2019 15:49:47 +0000. Up 16.22 seconds.
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 3324.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  54 M RSS (270 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sun Feb 10 15:49:45 2019 - 00:03 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3324
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.94-89.73.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2 will be an update
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1 will be updated
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package           Arch        Version                    Repository       Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel            x86_64      4.14.94-89.73.amzn2        amzn2-core       19 M
Updating:
 openssl           x86_64      1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2      amzn2-core      496 k
 openssl-libs      x86_64      1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2      amzn2-core      1.2 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Upgrade  2 Packages

Total download size: 21 M
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                               33 MB/s |  21 MB  00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                    1/5 
  Updating   : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                         2/5 
  Installing : kernel-4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64                            3/5 
  Cleanup    : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                         4/5 
  Cleanup    : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                    5/5 
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                    1/5 
  Verifying  : kernel-4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64                            2/5 
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                         3/5 
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                    4/5 
  Verifying  : 1:openssl-1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.1.x86_64                         5/5 

Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.94-89.73.amzn2                                           

Updated:
  openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2                                          
  openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.amzn2.0.2                                     

Complete!
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10007  100 10007    0     0  10007      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 99079
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/.nvm'

=> Profile not found. Tried  (as defined in $PROFILE), ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, and ~/.profile.
=> Create one of them and run this script again
=> Create it (touch ) and run this script again
   OR
=> Append the following lines to the correct file yourself:

export NVM_DIR="/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 4: /root/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 5: nvm: command not found
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 11772.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  52 M RSS (268 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sun Feb 10 15:50:08 2019 - 00:02 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 11772
No packages marked for update
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 2.17.2-2.amzn2 for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core-doc = 2.17.2-2.amzn2 for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core = 2.17.2-2.amzn2 for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: emacs-filesystem >= 25.3 for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::I18N) for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsecret-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs-filesystem.noarch 1:25.3-3.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
---> Package git-core.x86_64 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package git-core-doc.noarch 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package libsecret.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: perl-Git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.noarch
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-20.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17020-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package              Arch       Version                   Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 git                  x86_64     2.17.2-2.amzn2            amzn2-core     217 k
Installing for dependencies:
 emacs-filesystem     noarch     1:25.3-3.amzn2.0.1        amzn2-core      64 k
 git-core             x86_64     2.17.2-2.amzn2            amzn2-core     4.0 M
 git-core-doc         noarch     2.17.2-2.amzn2            amzn2-core     2.3 M
 libsecret            x86_64     0.18.5-2.amzn2.0.2        amzn2-core     153 k
 perl-Error           noarch     1:0.17020-2.amzn2         amzn2-core      32 k
 perl-Git             noarch     2.17.2-2.amzn2            amzn2-core      70 k
 perl-TermReadKey     x86_64     2.30-20.amzn2.0.2         amzn2-core      31 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+7 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 6.8 M
Installed size: 36 M
Downloading packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                               18 MB/s | 6.8 MB  00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : git-core-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64                               1/8 
  Installing : git-core-doc-2.17.2-2.amzn2.noarch                           2/8 
  Installing : libsecret-0.18.5-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                          3/8 
  Installing : 1:perl-Error-0.17020-2.amzn2.noarch                          4/8 
  Installing : perl-TermReadKey-2.30-20.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                    5/8 
  Installing : 1:emacs-filesystem-25.3-3.amzn2.0.1.noarch                   6/8 
  Installing : perl-Git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.noarch                               7/8 
  Installing : git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64                                    8/8 
  Verifying  : 1:emacs-filesystem-25.3-3.amzn2.0.1.noarch                   1/8 
  Verifying  : perl-TermReadKey-2.30-20.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                    2/8 
  Verifying  : 1:perl-Error-0.17020-2.amzn2.noarch                          3/8 
  Verifying  : libsecret-0.18.5-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64                          4/8 
  Verifying  : git-core-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64                               5/8 
  Verifying  : git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.x86_64                                    6/8 
  Verifying  : perl-Git-2.17.2-2.amzn2.noarch                               7/8 
  Verifying  : git-core-doc-2.17.2-2.amzn2.noarch                           8/8 

Installed:
  git.x86_64 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2                                                   

Dependency Installed:
  emacs-filesystem.noarch 1:25.3-3.amzn2.0.1                                    
  git-core.x86_64 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2                                              
  git-core-doc.noarch 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2                                          
  libsecret.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.amzn2.0.2                                         
  perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17020-2.amzn2                                           
  perl-Git.noarch 0:2.17.2-2.amzn2                                              
  perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-20.amzn2.0.2                                   

Complete!
Cloning into 'zero2architect'...
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 16: npm: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 17: node: command not found
Feb 10 15:50:16 cloud-init[3314]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [127]
Feb 10 15:50:16 cloud-init[3314]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Feb 10 15:50:16 cloud-init[3314]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 18.2-72.amzn2.0.6 finished at Sun, 10 Feb 2019 15:50:16 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 45.55 seconds
```

Comment: Assuming, you are using Amazon Linux 2, did you check information in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-cloud-init)?

Comment: Why don't you echo out some progress information in your userdata script, step by step, and then check the console output afterwards? Also, there's no need for sudo in userdata as it's already running as root.

Comment: @LechMigdal Yes I did, i don't really see any error, should I post the output here?

Comment: @jarmod how can I echo it out? and where will it store?

Comment: Just echo to stdout e.g. echo “Run yum update -y”. To view, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Comment: @MasnadNihit in the cloud-init-output.log you get output from all the commands that are run in the user data. Do you see some output there related to what you're sending with user data (so e.g. from yum update, etc.)?

Comment: @LechMigdal I added the cloud log here and it looks like the npms don't work.

Comment: @jarmod I pasted the cloud log here, in the question it looks like the npm command cant be found.

Comment: @MasnadNihit great, so you have something to start with. Take a look at the info after nvm installation "=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now: export NVM_DIR="/.nvm"". I would start there. I assume npm is available when you login to the machine via SSH?

Comment: @LechMigdal Yea I read that, and what I did was so for the new istance, I wrote it like this,` url -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash 
export NVM_DIR="/home/ec2-user/.nvm"
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

And then run it, but still it causes the same problem and when I open the machine via ssh node is still not available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your SGs and NACL configurations? You need to allow port 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS) in outbound SG rules - destination 0.0.0.0/0. You also need to allow the same on outbound NACL's rules and ephemeral ports on inbound rules. Makes sure that your instance is sitting in a public subnet (with route to IGW) and it has public/Elastic IPv4 attached to it.

If any one of those conditions is not met, your user data scrip will fail, since it need connection to the Internet (in your case).

If your instance is sitting in a private subnet, make sure that you are running NAT Gateway or NAT instance and that your route tables are properly configured, as well as SGs and NACLs. Also make sure that source/destination check is disabled on NAT instance if you are using it.

**UPDATE**

You log clearly says that you don't have `npm` and `node` installed so you need to pass installation instruction to the script as well.

```
npm install -y
```

is not the right way to install `npm`. You can follow these steps to install both `node` and `npm`.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install 4.4.5
```

This will install node version 4.4.5. If you want some other version of node to be installed, then change the number for whatever supported version.

Comment: It should work since when I ssh into the instance and do the following script from inside the instance it does the work, so I am assuming the configuration won't be the problem.